# What is the meaning of truck-worthy packing?

Tags: meaning

I have problem understanding the following statement in a trade context:

> The total price for this order is X Euro including truck-worthy packing and export permits.

What does the author mean by truck-worthy packing?

Answer (score 5):

He means "packed to prevent damage when transported by truck". 
This could be stable boxes, perhaps with packing peanuts or styrofoam, foil-wrapped on a pallet, liquid in approriate containers... whatever fits the goods.

---

Edit as requested:

[TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/worthy) gives the following definition for word-combos of the pattern *[noun]worthy*:

> **-worthy**
>   a combining form of worthy, used with the meanings “deserving of, fit for” (newsworthy; trustworthy), “capable of travel in or on” (roadworthy; seaworthy) the thing specified by the initial element.
>   *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.*

So using this definition:

-"truckworthy" means "fit to be transported in a truck" and

-"truckworthy packaging" a form of packaging that ensures said quality.  For examples, see original answer above.

Comment: Well done! I just [googled](https://www.google.com/?#q=%22truck-worthy%20packing%22) and this was the only page that came up! Could you add a little explanation of _how_ you figured out the meaning of this phrase? That might shed some more general light on how a fluent speaker makes sense of unfamiliar phrases (as suggested by [FumbleFingers' post here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/1349/6700) and, IMO, making the most interesting and useful answers).

Comment: @BenKovitz: I even found a dictionary definition (tucked in with a load of others), much to my surprise.... Was this edit what you had in mind?

Comment: Did you find the definition of _-worthy_ before or after you wrote your original answer? (I'm interested in how you actually figured it out, not whether you can find justification in a dictionary.)

Comment: Even as non-native speaker (I'm German), sometimes it's hard to say why you *know*. But I'll try to give my line of reasoning: Worthy has not only a sense of (monetary) value, but of fitness, appropriateness, being a good match... From there, truckworthy could only be worth *for* a truck (not worth a truck). Or, very sloppyly "good for transportation on a truck". Context is crucial, as usual. The examples in my answer are just common knowledge. If I hadn't found the dictionary entry (in <30 seconds & after your comment), I might have tried to put this line of thought into something readable.

Comment: I think _that_ is worthy of being included in your answer. :)

Comment: @BenKovitz: at 22:15 local time! After getting up at 4:30? If I can still write a coherent sentence ^_^

Comment: @BenKovitz - speaking as a native, I'm aware of the terms seaworthy and airworthy. These apply, as you might guess, to ships and aircraft, and in each case mean that the vehicle is suitable for use. It doesn't mean that they are _ready_ for use, since (for instance) each might need refueling, but be otherwise in good shape. With these as examples, "truckworthy" is a pretty obvious construction.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast That sounds worthy of an answer, too!